# Кто может помочь адаптировать страницу на сайте?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

не очень понимаю как работают меда запросы, может кто-то сможет помочь

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: FuturaBookC;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 {
    font-family: FuturaDemiC;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 25px;
}

ul, li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

section {
    padding-top: 160px;
}

section h1 {
    margin-bottom: 40px;

}

.container {
    max-width: 1170px;
    /*позиционирование по центру*/
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

.header {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #00a2ff, #00ffb4);
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    padding-top: 110px;
}

.header1 {
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;

    
}

header a {
    color: #000;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 450px;
    padding-top: 20px;

}

.menu li a {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.menu li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.menu li {
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.nav {
    align-items: center;
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
}

.offer {
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.offer p {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.offer-right {
    float: right;
}
.offer-right {
    margin-left: auto;
}


.one, .two, .three {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}


.des-1, .des-3{
    width: 450px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.for {
    display: flex;
}

.des-2, .des-4{
    width: 450px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.objective1 h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: FuturaDemiC;
    margin-bottom: 73px;
}

.obj-1, .obj-2, .obj-3, .obj-4{
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}

hr {
    border: none; 
    border-top: 2px solid #FFF623; 
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 70px;
}


.objj1, .objj2{
    margin-bottom: 73px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer{
    padding-top: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #757575;
}

.footer p{
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 1170px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 970px;
    }
  
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 750px;
    }


  
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
    .container {
        max-width: none;
    }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preload" href="/fonts/FuturaBookC.ttf" as="font">
    <link rel="preload" href="/fonts/FuturaDemiC.ttf" as="font">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
     <style type="text/css">
             @font-face {
    font-family: FuturaDemiC; 
    src: url(fonts/FuturaDemiC.ttf); 
   }
     @font-face {
    font-family: FuturaBookC; 
    src: url(fonts/FuturaBookC.ttf); 
   }
        </style>  
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header" class="header">
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="row">
            <div class="header1">
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul class="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Главная
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Руководитель
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Студенты
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Проекты
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="logo">
                <div class="offer">
                <h1> ПРОЕКТНАЯ <br>ЛАБОРАТОРИЯ </h1>
                <p>кафедра математики</p>
            </div>

            <div class="offer-right">
                <img src="img/logo-header.svg" alt="logo" style="margin-top: 100px; ">
            </div>
            
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section id="about" class="about">
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="description">
                <div class="one">
                    <div class="one1">
                    <img src="img/1.svg" style="width: 450px; " >
                </div>
                <div class="des-1">
                    <h1>Что такое лаборатория?</h1>
                    <p>Лаборатория - это обьединение единомышленчерез проведение различных мероприятий в активной форме</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
                <div class="des-2">
                    <h1>Чем мы занимаемся?</h1>
                    <p>Научной, прикладной и творческой деятельностью</p>
                </div>
                <div class="two2">
                    <img src="img/2.svg" style="width: 450px; " >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="three">
                <div class="three3">
                <img src="img/3.svg" style="width: 450px; ">
            </div>
            <div class="des-3">
                <h1>для чего?</h1>
                <p>У участников появляется возможность не только развить свой потенциал, но и пробовать себя в других направлениях деятельности через мастер-классы, исследовательскую и творческую деятельность.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="for">
                <div class="des-4">
                    <h1>присоединяйся</h1>
                    <p>Нет иерархии в отношениях участников. Задачи решаются совместно, согласовано, происходит обмен знаниями. Такой подход к работе является очень эффективным.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="for4">
                    <img src="img/4.svg" alt="" style="width: 450px; " >
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="objective" class="objective" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="objective1">
                <h1>основные задачи лаборатории</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="objj1">
            <div class="obj-1">
                <hr align="center" > 
                <p>повышение проффесионального мастерства учеников</p>
            </div>
            <div class="obj-2">
                <hr align="center" > 
                <p>поддерка творческой молодежи, использующей в своей работе инновационный и передовой опыт</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="objj2">
            <div class="obj-3">
                <hr align="center" >
                <p>совершенствование подходов к организации образовательного и творческого процесса с ориентацией на развитие личности   </p>
            </div>
            <div class="obj-4">
                <hr align="center" >
                <p>представлению возможности для самореализации и развития потенциала</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <footer id="footer" class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer-text">
                <p>©1994—2021 УГНТУ</p>
                <p>koledinsrg@gmail.com</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icons">
                <a class="instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/bni_rusoil/">
                    <img src="img/inst.svg" alt="">
                </a>
                <a class="vk" href="https://m.vk.com/digital_track?from=groups%253Fact%253Dlist"><img src="img/vk.svg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Перед тем как задавать вопросы, стоит обращаться в документацию, т.к. документации по медиа запросам очень много, но всё же я продублирую её сюда

Медиазапросы — это модуль CSS3, который позволяет создавать отзывчивые веб-сайты, используя различные правила стилей для разных устройств или типов носителей. В зависимости от этих правил содержимое отображается в соответствии с различными условиями, например размером экрана, окна браузера или самого устройства, а также ориентацией и разрешением устройства.

В общем случае медиа-запрос состоит из ключевого слова, описывающего тип устройства (необязательный параметр) и выражения, проверяющего характеристики данного устройства. Из всех характеристик чаще всего проверяется ширина устройства width. Медиа-запрос является логическим выражением, которое возвращает истину или ложь.

@media (rules) - используется для применения стилей на определенных носителях, размерах экрана и т.д. Это позволяет нам указать различные варианты дизайна в зависимости от размера экрана. Затем страницу можно оптимизировать и показывать совершенно по-разному для мобильных телефонов, планшетов и разных размеров окон браузера.

@media (min-width: 500px) - говорит о том, что стили, которые указаны внутри этого медиа-правила, будут применены при минимальной ширине экрана 500px и шире.

@media (max-width: 500px) - говорит о том, что стили, которые указаны внутри этого медиа-правила, будут применены от нуля до максимальной ширины экрана в 500px.

P.S. Чтобы сайт корректно отображался на других устройствах лучше копировать весь код от прошлого медиа запроса, или стандартный, а потом менять под свои нужды...

Пример медиа запроса:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background-color: #885053;
  }
}
```

Более подробно можно почитать тут - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries